# Allow public usage of WebService DNN API

Tags: web-services, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

I have some webservices which only logged on users can use. However, I need one to allow public access and to non-registered members to use as well.

I have given my DNN module permissions to be viewed by Unauthorized and All users and my webmethod as such:

```
   <HttpGet>
    Public Function FindSomeone(q As String) As HttpResponseMessage
        Try
            Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "ok".ToJson)

        Catch exc As Exception
            Return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, exc)
        End Try
    End Function
```

I have tried adding:

```
<DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel:=SecurityAccessLevel.View)>
```

and

```
 <DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel:=SecurityAccessLevel.Anonymous)>
```

but it still doesn't work for users who are not logged on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the services completely open, add the `<AllowAnonymous>` attribute.